# Java multiple dispatch example

Tags: java, dynamic, dispatch

Recently, I have been learning about multiple dispatch in Java. I tried out an example, and I want to know if I am on the right track.

I created a parent class called Dispatch and three child classes named One, Two, and Three. In class Dispatch, I created a function called display(), which displays the class name of its arguments.

```
public class Dispatch {
    void display(Dispatch d1, Dispatch d2){
        System.out.println("Method in "+ this.getClass().getName() +" prints: "+ d1.getClass().getName()+", "+ d2.getClass().getName());
    }
}

public class One extends Dispatch {
}

public class Two extends Dispatch{
}

public class Three extends Dispatch{
}


//In main function in another class, Application.java:
Dispatch one = new One();
Dispatch two = new Two();
Dispatch three = new Three();

one.display(two, three);
```

The output was exactly as I expected:

```
Method disp() in One prints: Two, Three
```

I just want to know if I got the concept of multiple dispatch right, or if this is merely an inaccurate workaround. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question might be better suited for [codereview.se] (though read their question guidelines first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuu don't need toString functions in each of those classes. This code will do your job

```
void display(Dispatch d1, Dispatch d2){
    System.out.println("Method in "+ this.getClass().getName() +" prints: "+ d1.getClass().getName()+", "+ d2.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I noted this down. So apart from this, did I implement multiple dispatch well? Am I conceptually right?

Comment: Yes. You have understood inheritance and polymorphisim